# JavaScript-using loops

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just started a web programming class and we've started working with JavaScript. Currently I have to take a web page I've already written and add some JavaScript to it. I'm getting hung up at the beginning were we add a class to each thumbnail image on the page (I've already done this).

Then in the .js file we're suppose to write a loop that seeks out all the img tags with the new class (with a hint to use querySelectorAll()). I've been over the lectures, the book and multiple tutorials but for some reason its just not clicking. I don't even know how to start writing this. If someone could provide some guidance I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: post what you have tried

Comment: `var theImages = document.querySelectorAll("img.yourClassNameHere");` - exactly what it tells you to do.

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelectorAll` returns an `NodeList` of all the elements matching your selector.

The class selector is the dot (.), so if you have a list of images like:

```
<img src="image1.jpg" class="thumbnail" />
<img src="image2.jpg" class="thumbnail" />
<img src="image3.jpg" class="thumbnail" />
```

Something like:

`document.querySelectorAll('.thumbnail');`

will return a `NodeList`, with all the elements that match your selector.

then you can just iterate over the `NodeList`, and access each element individually like:

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll('.thumbnail');
for(var i = 0; i < images.length; ++i) {
    var image = images[i];
    console.log(image.src); // output: image1.jpg, image2.jpg, image3.jpg
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**First**, select all the images you have as:

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll(".className");
```

**Second**, do what ever you want with that selected images as:

```
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++){
    //Do you code here
}
```